# Dart calling a member function by function name

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I am wondering if there is anyway to call a function by its name in dart [as in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string).

I would like to do something as such:

```
foo["bar"]();
```

Comment: That seems to be only for mirrors? There is no way to do this for Elements?

Answer (score 7):

I don't want readers to think what the questioner wants isn't possible in Dart, so I'm adding an answer.

You need to use Mirrors to call a method if you have its name available as a string.  Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Foo {
  bar() => "bar";
}

void main() {
  var foo = new Foo();

  var mirror = reflect(foo);
  print(mirror.invoke(#bar, []).reflectee); // Prints 'bar'.
}
```