# Get function from function name in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, dart, flutter

For a cross-platform (iOS, android) project I consider using [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org) with UI-Programming in [Flutter](https://flutter.io).

For straight-forward translation of present Kotlin code, I want to call functions by their function name. To be more precise, I am looking for how to write the function getFunctionByName such that the following code prints "The answer is 42."?

```
void function42(String s) {
    print(s + " 42.");
}

void main() {
    int number = 42;
    String calculatedFunctionName = "function" + number.toString();
    String calculatedArgument = "The answer is";
    Function f = getFunctionByName(calculatedFunctionName);
    f(calculatedArgument);
}
```

What I try to achieve [works in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34824324/get-function-by-name-dynamically-in-kotlin) and seems to [work in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19718821/dart-calling-a-member-function-by-function-name), but when I tried the linked Dart code in a Flutter project, the import

```
import 'dart:mirrors';
```

does not work for me. There is a whole [thread about reflection in Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150), which I interpret such that at the time of writing reflection does not work in Flutter. But maybe there is a workaround for the specific thing I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Flutter. Flutter disable `dart:mirror` to make binaries smaller.

Instead flutter (and now angulardart) uses code generation as an alternative.

Dart comes with a really powerful code generators tool : [build](https://github.com/dart-lang/build/tree/master/build)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Searching for code generation, I found the reflectable library for Flutter (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable). While I did not get the code running yet, it sounds like it should be possible with this library.

Comment: Getting Reflectable to run with Flutter turned out to be more difficult than I thought. I opened a new question that focusses on Reflectable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169706/flutter-reflection-with-reflectable-working-example-needed