# Flutter Reflection with Reflectable: working example needed

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to achieve reflection in a cross-platform (iOS, Android) project using [Flutter](https://flutter.io) and the [Reflectable package](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable). To keep the binaries short, this package uses code generation.

However, following the [tutorial/readme](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable) of this package, I am not able to generate the needed code, in this case the file main.reflectable.dart. While I have reached the point where things work without error, code generation concludes with the statement:

```
[INFO] Succeeded after 88ms with 0 outputs
```

In the following I try to show a reproducible path of what I did. For that I moved flutter to a different path and reinstalled it, but didn't reinstall the flutter plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.

**How to reproduce / What I did?**

I) **Install Flutter** as usual for Mac. On the command line:

```
cd ~/development 
git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
export PATH=/Users/yourname/development/flutter/bin:$PATH 
flutter doctor
```

II) **Create a new Flutter project** in IntelliJ IDEA

1. Choose SDK path: /Users/yourname/development/flutter
2. Choose project location: ~/gitroot/PlayGround/reflectable_test_2
3. Add directory entry_point parallel to lib directory
4. Add dart file main.dart inside directory entry_point
5. Get the content for main.dart from the main.dart in https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable (a lot will be shown red)
6. Delete main.dart from lib directory (unchecked "safe delete" and "search in comments")
7. Delete widet_test.dart in test directory
8. Add "reflectable: any" to pubspec.yaml under dependencies
9. In main.dart, click run and in the upcoming dialog set the entry point to /Users/yourname/gitroot/PlayGround/reflectable_test_2/entry_point/main.dart

When the dependencies are loaded, some of the red wiggles will go away, but not the one in "import 'main.reflectable.dart';", since this file does not exist yet.

III) **Try to generate main.reflectable.dart** with the builder on the command line:

```
cd /Users/yourname/gitroot/PlayGround/reflectable_test_2/
flutter packages pub run build_runner build entry_point
```

Note that instead of the last line, the tutorial only says

```
pub run build_runner build DIR
```

but the used line is indeed [correct when used in a Flutter project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19049). Following the readme/tutorial so far, I got the result:

```
Package "build_runner" is not an immediate dependency.
Cannot run executables in transitive dependencies.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

IV) In IntelliJ, add "build_runner: any" to dev_dependencies in pubspec.yaml. Run again on the command line (flutter packages pub run build_runner build entry_point). This results in the output:

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 506ms

[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 776ms

[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 3ms

[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Running build completed, took 7ms

[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 69ms

[INFO] Succeeded after 88ms with 0 outputs
```

To summarise, no errors, but it didn't create the file main.reflectable.dart either (0 outputs). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: what was the solution for you ? I have same problem.

Comment: @mohammad I too was struggling with this, it only worked for me once I added a build.yaml as shown below, you can copy it from the example repo that Erik linked to. Or copy it from below, just change entry_point/main.dart to lib/main.dart and save in root of project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the only missing bit is to do

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build entry_point/main.dart`

or add a `build.yaml` file along the lines of

`targets:
  test_reflectable:
    builders:
      reflectable:
        generate_for:
          - entry_point/main.dart`

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/eernstg/reflectable-flutter)'s an **example repo** which may serve as a very simplistic starting point for reflectable in Flutter.

Edit 2: There is a [whitelist](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/glossary#entrypoint-directory) of locations where `pub` supports entry points ("Dart programs"), and `entry_point` is not on that list. Try using a directory which is present in the whitelist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the example repo works for me.The first suggestion above does not seem to make a difference. The second suggestion -- after modifying the target to reflectable_test_2 -- did not seem to make a difference either. It's still 0 outputs. But since the original question was asking for a working example, I marked this to solve the question.

Comment: I fetched the example repo again and ran the commands as described in the README.md. It does generate code as expected for me. If something still doesn't work then please create an issue on https://github.com/eernstg/reflectable-flutter.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have these both packages added in **pubspec.yaml**

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: any  
  built_value_generator: any
```

if only **build_runner** is added. it won't be going to generate anything and end up with success.

also, check your **main.dart**

```dart
//reflectable impoort statement should be like this 
import 'main.reflectable.dart' show initializeReflectable;

void main(){

 // initialize Reflectable in main

initializeReflectable();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now try to build with the command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build DIR
```

if it's working then you are damn lucky.

Now let's add a **build.yaml** file manually (same directory of pubspec.yaml)

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      reflectable:
        generate_for:
          - lib/main.dart
```

Now try command

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build DIR
```